# Storing Oracle data into hadoop layer without using Scoop

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

With the below script am trying to save oracle output into an text file in hadoop space.

```
#!/bin/bash
DBUSER='scott'
DBUSERPASSWORD='tiger'
DB='oracle'

sqlplus -s <<EOF
${DBUSER}/${DBUSERPASSWORD}@${MYDB}
set linesize 32767
set feedback off
set heading off

select * from dual;

EOF

hive -f HiveQueries.hql
```

The script is called from Hive command prompt, is there a way to save the output of the above query in hive directory as a file, I understand my oracle server is different and coding needs to be changed.
But instead of using sqoop i wanted to save the output file into hadoop

Comment: **1.** set up SQL\*Plus to convert text to UTF-8 and use a specific column delimiter, e.g. TAB, and *spool* output to a local file (cf. Oracle documentation...) **2.** `hdfs dfs -moveFromLocal [spool.out] [some HDFS directory]` **3.** create an EXTERNAL Hive table located on that directory, using the Text SerDe with the appropriate delimiter, and optionally skipping N header records on each file **4.** enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

Why use command-line utilities *(a fat Oracle client requiring a license fee, by the way)* and text files when you can use JDBC connectivity to "pump" Oracle data straight into a Hive table??

https://github.com/qubole/Hive-JDBC-Storage-Handler

Comment: Seems a good option to try but am from testing team so don't have much of implementation access... And new to java and scripting... So is there any way for achieving this from command line?